# C++: calling same function of multiple classes

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to call the same function in multiple classes without having to make separate functions for each class.

Example:

```
class A{
public:
void update();
}

class B{
public:
void update();
}
```

Now i want to create a function that can take both `class A` or `class B` and call the `update()` function. I have been looking for a solution on stack overflow / google but can't find anything. I was looking at templates but was not able to find anything that works. In my project I have around five or six classes each having a `update()` function needing to be called every frame. I am using a common base class but the `update()` function needs to be located in the derived class. I had the same issue at my last project and can't figure this out.

Comment: `template <typename T> void callUpdate(T& obj) { obj.update(); }`

Comment: You have heard of virtual functions?

Comment: Thank you! this was what i was looking for. now just need to look more into templates in headers files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why can't you define an pure virtual update method in your base class? (Or even a second base class/Interface which only has this virtual method.)

```
class IUpdate
{
    public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
}

class A : public IUpdate
{
    public:
    void update();
}
```

And the same for class B.

Comment: Why is this answer down-voted? Best solution is to create an interface using pure virtual functions.

Comment: Thank you I will look into this as it seems more logical than templates. I will set as solved when i got it working.

Comment: It worked thank you! saved me a lot of headache of copying same function for diffrent classes.